# Cobertura code coverage test on Maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

I'm trying to generate a code coverage report for a simple Maven plugin I've developed. Cobertura generates the report with the three classes in my project correctly, but it reports 0% code coverage even though the tests execute successfully. I've run it in debug mode and there are no errors or stack traces reported by Cobertura.

My configuration in the POM file is quite simple:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <!-- version 2.1 uses sonatype aether. anything after 2.1 uses eclipse aether. -->
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.twdata.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>mojo-executor-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-custom-plugin</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                        <forkCount>0</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>MyCustomPlugin</goalPrefix>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>help-descriptor</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Cobertura works on all of my other projects (so far), is there any reason that it would failing to report coverage for a Maven plugin project?

Comment: Please show your full pom file otherwise it's hard to see what's going on.

Comment: @khmarbaise: I've added more details from the POM

Comment: First i doubt that your dependencies in particular to maven-assembly-plugin, maven-resources-plugin make sense apart from that where have you located your tests. Will the tests being reported to be executed? `mvn clean test`? Are the mojo's being extracted? Can you show the output? Furthermore what kind of plugin do you like to write? Really needed?

Comment: @khmarbaise: running `mvn clean test` works and generates a surefire test report. The plugin does some special work in which it builds assemblies, resource packages, and artifacts based on configurations that are needed for a very specific situation here (we can do it without a plugin, but the POM file to do that is way too large and complicated and no one wants to maintain it). The Test output appears twice in the console, for some strange reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was with my surefire configuration. I changed it to

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-custom-plugin</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and reports are now generated correctly. I got the idea for changing the fork options from a number of posts I'd seen of similar problems related to generating reports for sonar plugins, and changing the fork options resolved the issue.